# Conversion from Base 10 to Base 2

Tags: java, binary, converters

I am trying to convert a number in base 10 to a number in base 2, but I have a problem. When I run the code, I get the base 2 number in the wrong order. For example, I input 54 and get 110110 instead of 011011, the correct value.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class DecimalToBinary
{
public static void main(String arg[]){   
  int quotient;
  int remainder;

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter a decimal number:"); 
  quotient = keyboard.nextInt();  

  do {
     remainder = quotient % 2;
     quotient = quotient / 2;

    // String x = String.valueOf(remainder);
    // System.out.print(x);
  System.out.print (remainder);

  } while (quotient != 0);
   }  
   }
```

Comment: You can always revert what you get.

Comment: you could put the `remainder` value into a stack and print it out after the iteration is complete or into an array and reverse the order

Comment: You don't have base 10. `nextInt()` delivers a binary integer, base 2. What you are actually doing is converting binary to printable ASCII.

Comment: It is not in the wrong order, it is because Java are using the sequence Big-Endian to array the bits. If you need Little-Endian you must revert the bits.

Comment: @JorgeOmarMedra It is because *this code* produces the least significant bit first. It has nothing to do with big/little-endian.

Comment: @EJP you are right this issue is in BITS and the concept that i used it for BYTES. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java has a built-in method to do this:

```
Integer.toString(int i, int radix);
```

where

- `i` is your base ten number, and
- `radix` is the base you want it in, in your case, 2.

It will return a string in binary.

Answer (score 4):

Another inbuilt java function for this is

```
Integer.toBinaryString(int num)
```

where num is the base 10 number you want to convert

Answer (score 2):

Base 10 to Base 2 should Reverse output,I think you can use `array`,then reverse output `array`

```
 public static void main(String arg[]){
        int quotient;
        int remainder;
        List<Integer> arrayList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a decimal number:");
        quotient = keyboard.nextInt();

        do {
            remainder = quotient % 2;
            quotient = quotient / 2;

            // String x = String.valueOf(remainder);
            // System.out.print(x);
           // System.out.print (remainder);
            arrayList.add(remainder);

        } while (quotient != 0);
        ListIterator<Integer> li;
        for (li = arrayList.listIterator(); li.hasNext();) {// 将游标定位到列表结尾
            li.next();
        }
        for (; li.hasPrevious();) {// 逆序输出列表中的元素
            System.out.print(li.previous() + " ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution, its simple:

```
  int quotient;
      int remainder;

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("Please enter a decimal number:"); 
      quotient = keyboard.nextInt();  
      Stack<Integer> s=new Stack<Integer>();
      do {
         remainder = quotient % 2;
         quotient = quotient / 2;
         s.add(remainder);
        // String x = String.valueOf(remainder);
        // System.out.print(x);
      //System.out.print (remainder);
      } while (quotient != 0);
      while(!s.isEmpty()){
          System.out.print(s.pop());

      }
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix your code

```
public class CustomDecimalToBinary {
    public static void Dec2Bin() {
        int quotient;
        int remainder;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a decimal number:");
        quotient = keyboard.nextInt();

        do {
            remainder = quotient % 2;

            // String x = String.valueOf(remainder);
            // System.out.print(x);
            System.out.print (remainder);

        } while ((quotient /= 2) != 0);
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Please enter a decimal number:
54
011011
```

EDIT: It appears I solved the problem to get your desired output but your code produces the correct output...

Comment: The binary representation of 54 is not 011011. That is the binary representation of 27. The binary representation of 54 is 110110. You have merely reproduced the OP's problem.